# Is it possible to drag the marker in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to drag the marker, currently clicking on the charts able to get new marker using the plotline in highcharts!
is it possible to hold/grab the marker line and drag it on the chart?

[CLICK ON THE PLOTLINE](http://jsfiddle.net/rGCX4/8/)

```
  var chart = this.xAxis[0];


                            chart.removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
                            chart.addPlotLine({
                                value: event.xAxis[0].value,
                                color: '#FF0000',
                                width: 2,
                                id: 'plot-line-1'
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Highcharts' draggable plugin: `jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/`

Comment: This is dragging the points and series value. But my question was to drag the marker and get the marker value. In the above, JSFIDDLE I have achieved using clicking anywhere on chart.

Comment: What do you mean by marker? Marker is point's element. To get marker value when clicked, use point.events.click.

Comment: I know to fetch the value by using the click events. But, I wanted to know how to drag the marker in the graph. Your earlier comment gives and idea of how to drag the points.

Comment: So, you want to drag in marker and by this add new point? Something like this is not supported.

Comment: NO, .... I just Click and drag the marker on the chart and point where I exit the mouse/click. I just want to grab x-axis value.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what do you want to achieve.. Maybe you just want to use selection event, with disabled zooming in..?

Comment: Yes, you are right... I needed the selection event not the zooming.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34225/discussion-between-john-smith-and-pawel-fus)

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines.events

Supported properties are `click`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mousemove`. These events are not enough to implement the dragging option for the marker(PlotLine). Atleast not in a neat way.

Comment: Other events, like `mousedown` and `mouseup`, also work. _Now_ is it enough?

Comment: Great to know. I believe so, but it won't be as easy as adding an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning an on event to the svg element:

http://jsfiddle.net/yem93w5o/1/

var line, clickY;

```
    var start = function (e) {

$(document).bind({
    'mousemove.line': step,
        'mouseup.line': stop
});

    clickY = e.pageY - line.translateY;
    }

    var step = function (e) {
        line.translate(0, e.pageY - clickY)
    }

    var stop = function () {
        $(document).unbind('.line');
    }
```

(...)

```
line = chart.highcharts().yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.translate(0,0).on('mousedown', start);
```